# ldifファイルの投入について

Tags: centos, ldap, openldap

メールアカウントの管理をするために、
LDAPを用いたいと思っております。

OpenLDAPのインストールは完了し、
次に設定をおこないたいのですが、
エントリ登録がうまくできません。

現環境:

- ドメイン名: local
- LDAPサーバーホスト名: mailsvr-01.local
- LDAPクライアントホスト名: mailcli-01.local

LDAPクライアントホストに下記のユーザーがいる:

- cliuser01
- cliuser02

この環境の場合に、
エントリ登録を書いてみたのですが、
下記のエラーが表示されてしまいます。

```
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
```

なお、エントリ登録のldifファイルは下記になります:

```
# cat test1.ldif
dn: dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local
objectClass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
dc: mailsvr-01
o: mailsvr-01.local

dn: cn=Manager,dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: Manager

dn: ou=Users,dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Users

dn: ou=Group,dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Group
```

登録コマンド:

```
ldapadd -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local" -W -f test1.ldif
```

やりたいこととしては、LDAPサーバーでLDAPクライアントに存在する、
二つのユーザのメールアカウントを管理して、
メールアカウントのパスワード変更の際にも、LDAPを通じて認証を行うというものです。

以上、初歩的な質問ではありますが、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: CentOS のバージョンはいくつですか? バージョンによって `slapd.conf`(5) がデフォルトか `slapd-config`(5) がデフォルトかの違いがあります。どちらを使っているかわかっているなら、その情報でもいいです。

Comment: @fumiyasさん
CentOSのバージョンは6.6になります。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Invalid credentials (49)` とのことなので、以下のいずれかが原因だと思われます。これを解消してください。

- `ldapadd`(1) に渡した `cn=Manager,dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local` のパスワードが間違っている。
- `cn=Manager,dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local` が `slapd.conf`(5) (あるいは `slapd-config`(5)) の `rootdn` (`olcRootDN`) に設定されていない、かつ LDAP DIT にも存在しない。
- `rootdn` (`olcRootDN`) に設定しているなら、`rootpw` (`olcRootPW`) が設定されていない、あるいは値がおかしい。
- LDAP DIT に存在するなら、そのエントリに `userPassword` 属性が付いていない、あるいは値がおかしい、あるいはパスワードポリシー(`slapo-ppolicy`(5))で無効化されている。

もしくは、書き込み権がある有効なユーザー+パスワード、あるいはローカルユーザー (ldapi で接続し SASL EXTERNAL) でバインドしてください。

Comment: @fumiyasさん
ありがとうございます。
>ldapadd(1) に渡した cn=Manager,dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local のパスワードが間違っている。

やはりパスワードが間違っていたようで、正しいパスワードを入力したら下記のようなメッセージが出力されました。

[root@mailsvr-01 openldap]# ldapadd -x -D "cn=Manager,dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local" -W -f /tmp/tmp.ldif
Enter LDAP Password:
adding new entry "dc=mailsvr-01,dc=local"
ldap_add: Naming violation (64)
        additional info: value of single-valued naming attribute 'dc' conflicts with value present in entry

エントリの追加はできたようにもみえるのですが、なおエラーのメッセージ(名前の衝突？)が出力されております。

こちらはどのようなことが考えられるでしょうか。
たびたびお手数ではございますが、教えていただけましょうでしょうか。

Comment: 私の回答の通りの原因で問題が解決したのであれば、回答を採用してもらえないでしょうか。

`Naming Violation (64)` となる原因は、追加しようとしているエントリの RDN (例えば `dc=xxx`) の値 (`xxx`) が属性の値と異っている (`dc: xxx` になってない) せいではないかと。

Comment: @fumiyasさん

ありがとうございます。回答の方採用しました。
ご指摘のある部分を見直してみます。